# ¿cómo hago para crear un bucle? y no repetir las mismas acciones (python)

Tags: python, bucle-for

¡buenos días! apreciada comunidad, quería preguntar ¿cómo puedo crear un bucle o alguna otra acción para repetir una misma acción?

si es crear una lista, quisiera pedirle el favor ¿cómo puedo crear la lista e iterar con ella?

estoy aprendiendo eso, pero quiero profesionalizarme mas iterando con las listas.

agradezco esa información.

```py
import pywhatkit
import time
import pyautogui

texto = "¡buenas noches!"

n1 = "+57numecelular"
n2 = "+57numecelular"
n3 = "+57numecelular"
n4 = "+57numecelular"


pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(n1,texto)
time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "w")

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(n2,texto)
time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "w")

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(n3,texto)
time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "w")

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(n4,texto)
time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "w")

Agradezco la ayuda.
```

Comment: Crea una lista con los números e itera en ella

Comment: Sumando a lo que dijeron los compañeros, es mejor cuando el código está como texto, [formateado](/help/formatting). Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Comment: En lugar de `n1, n2, n3, ...` usa una lista `n`. Luego puedes iterar sobre la lista. Cada elemento será un número telefónico.

Comment: Ya coloqué el código en texto, me gustaría saber ¿cómo puedo crear esa lista e iterar con ella?

Comment: Puedes armar una lista colocando cada elemento separado por comas y rodearlo de corchetes. Por ejemplo `['numero1', 'numero2', ...]`. [En google puedes hayar muchos tutoriales sobre el tema](https://www.google.com/search?q=listas+python&rlz=1C1CHBD_esAR1006AR1006&oq=listas+python&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l4j69i60l3.2258j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). También hay mucho sobre el bucle for: https://www.google.com/search?q=bucle+form+python&rlz=1C1CHBD_esAR1006AR1006&oq=bucle+form+python&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i13l5j0i10i22i30j0i5i13i30l3.2900j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: yo comprendo lo de la lista, pero ¿Cómo creo el bucle for? ¿alguna tentativa para probarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que buscas es la sentencia `for`, la cual funciona pasandole un objeto iterador y un iterable. El bucle tomara un iterador desde el iterable hasta que ya no se tenga uno nuevo. Aqui algunos ejemplos de como usar un bucle for:

```
        >>> for i in range(4):
            print(i)
[output]    
            0
            1
            2
            3

        >>> items = [18,2]
        >>> for item in items:
                print(f'El numero es {item}')
[output]      
            El numero es 18
            El numero es 2
```

Y basado en tu necesidad, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import time

import pywhatkit
import pyautogui

TEXTO = "¡buenas noches!"
NUMEROS = [
    "+57numecelular",
    "+57numecelular",
    "+57numecelular",
    "+57numecelular",
]

for numero in numeros: # for i in range(len(NUMEROS)):
    # pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(NUMEROS[i], texto)
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(NUMEROS,TEXTO) 
    time.sleep(10)
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "w")
```

He puesto en comentarios (el texto seguido de `#` es un comentario) la manera alternativa de hacerlo iterando sobre indices como te indican en los comentarios.

Con el uso de funciones, yo lo haria asi:

```
def my_fun(x):
     pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(x,TEXTO)
     time.sleep(10)
     pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "w")

TEXTO = "¡buenas noches!"
NUMEROS = [
    "+57numecelular",
    "+57numecelular",
    "+57numecelular",
    "+57numecelular",
]

[my_fun(x) for x in NUMEROS]
```

Esto ultimo se llama comprension de listas y tal vez lo encuentres interesante

Comment: Yo no usaría comprensión de listas en este caso. Piensa que estarías creando una lista llena de None sin ningún proposito. Se pierde efectividad y velocidad. Pero gracias por la respuesta y por explicarle como funciona un bucle for :D